# JavaMail:debug listInfo is null and throw folderNotFoundException

Tags: jakarta-mail

I create a folder in the qq page side, with javamail collected on the phone side found that the folder does not exist, breakpoint debugging found the following error.

[image: li == null ?]

[image: throw folderNotFoundException]

I remember before it is possible, and now qq and Tencent E-mail are not, Netease me through the way under the test, no problem

oh,my god! what happend!

20171018 Resolve the update

Well, I found qq in the web side of the establishment of the folder are stored in the default "other folder" this directory, so the full name of the folder name should be "other folder / xxxfolerName" this form, so this is not javamail problem is qq side of the problem, QQ really wonderful work

Finally, thank you all.

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image.

Comment: This is the wrong screenshot, not the code

Comment: Sigh.  It looks like you disassembled the JavaMail code.  You know you can look at the real [JavaMail source code](https://github.com/javaee/javamail), right?  As for your problem, what does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?  That will let us know if your IMAP server is correctly telling JavaMail about the folder you created.

Comment: These two screenshots is debugging javamail source screenshot, javamail source I did not modify the process is this:
I was in the qq page to establish the folder, and then the client is written in JavaMail, and then pull the folder list, when debugging to folder.exists (), javamail thrown an exception, the screenshot is abnormal li == null, so i was thinking of javamail itself bug?

Comment: Bill Shannon,you have qq account, I can contact you, more detailed to describe you,thank you first